# How to ask a question where an excess of an emotion is specified?

Tags: questions

An example of the type of sentence which I am attempting to address is:

- Chloe felt too scared to go skydiving.

If one wanted to ask which emotion she felt too much of to go skydiving, how should the question be posed?

Comment: You've used the question already. What's wrong with "Which emotion did she feel too much of to go skydiving"?

Comment: Oh yes, I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you.

Comment: What is the context for the question about emotion? If it's a reading comprehension test question asked about a sentence (or longer passage) that the test takers will have read then Andrew's suggestion is fine. If it's a real life situation it would be more natural to ask "Why didn't Chloe go skydiving?" without presupposing that the reason was emotional.

Comment: I'll note that the answer to *Which emotion did she feel?* would not be *scared* (an adjective), but ***fear*** (a noun).

Comment: "How are you feeling?" But then how many different emotions could you feel to not go skydiving...I think 'fear' is the only one.